# Is there a Stack Exchange site for web application administrators?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked this question on the "Web Applications" site:
[When using Microsoft Migration Manager to convert from Google Workspace, are the Sharing settings converted?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/169462/when-using-microsoft-migration-manager-to-convert-from-google-workspace-are-the)

I was told that Web Applications isn't the correct site:

"Thanks for your reply. It looks that the question is related to administering a web application (as a system / application manager) rather than using it (as end-user). While questions about using the web front end for users might be on topic, questions beyond using them as end-user are off-topic."

Okay....
What would be the correct site for this question?

Comment: Welcome to [meta.se]. The question posted in [webapps.se], besides looking to be about administering a web application, it looks to be way too broad. By the other hand, questions on each site of the [se] network should be self contained. Considering this, please [edit] this question to add a more details about what you want to ask, or a sample question.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Manager Migration is component of Microsoft 365 that is the new name of the product family that nowadatys emcompases multiple services, incluing among others Microsoft Office 365 and Sharepoint.

Moving files that one company managed in Google Workspace that was adquired by another company that manage files in "MS Office 365" is not a complex "task".

Below there is a couple of sites that might help with technical questions:

From https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-oldest

> [**Server Fault**](https://serverfault.com)
> is Q&A for system and network administrators

> [**Sharepoint**](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)
> Q&A for SharePoint enthusiasts

There are other sites that might also help, but lets keep this  answer focuced the above sites. The tags mentioned are only examples of tags that might be related.

## Server Fault

They have [[microsoft-office-365]](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-365) with more than 1,000 questions. Its tag excerpt says the following:

> Office 365 is Microsoft's subscription based cloud solution for business productivity. All server side components are hosted at Microsoft managed datacentres. Customers that subscribe to O365 have access to the latest business productivity software and can choose to be "entirely cloud based" or have a hybrid configuration where some on-premise servers are retained.

Also they have [[active-directory]](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/active-directory) with almost 10,000 questions. Its tag excerpt says the following:

> A Microsoft technology that constitutes an LDAP directory service with centralized management functionality for user accounts, computer accounts, groups, and configuration management across many Windows servers and desktops.

## Sharepoint

[sharepoint-online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-online) has more than 20,000 questions. Its tag excerpt says:

> for questions completely specific to the MS-provided SharePoint Cloud Service (Office 365's SharePoint Online/BPOS)